# How to watch a Pod api endpoint in a Kubernetes Operator using the SDK

Tags: kubernetes

**Description**

I have a CR associated with a POD with a container that is exposing an API, eg:

```
/available
```

returning for example

```
{"available":"true"}
```

Is there a way to create a controller watcher on that API call that whenever the response changes will trigger the reconcile function?
I believe it *could* be possible using a channel with the controller watcher, but I don't see any similar examples out there

**Using**

Kubernetes operator-sdk version v0.5.0+git

Comment: Not sure, can you check this doc on `Liveness and Readiness Probes`- https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-liveness-readiness-probes/

Comment: thanks, but not really asking about Liveness/Readiness Probe

Comment: I think, you can use Liveness/Readiness probe concept to modify according to your own.

Comment: Can you describe why the Liveness probe is not good for your use case? By reconcile function do you mean kill the pod and start a new one or something internal to your system?

Comment: @Maciek because Liveness and Readiness have a different purpose from my api.
No, the reconcile is a defined function for the Operator:
https://github.com/operator-framework/operator-sdk/blob/master/doc/user-guide.md#reconcile-loop

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid it's not as easy as you hope. The Kubernetes controller objects react to add/edit/delete operations of some kind of resource in the cluster. A value exposed inside an API of something running inside the Pod is not visible in the resource database. There is not event going off, notifying about the change either.

I see two things you can consider doing:

1. Create a regular controller that would have the reconcile function triggered fairly often, but would check the `availability` value inside it's reconcile function. If it changed, it would do something, if it didn't it would do nothing.
2. Just create a separate task, outside the controller domain, that would monitor this API value and do something.

Controllers work using notifications, they don't actively watch for changes, they are notified about them. That's different than what you want to do - periodically check the API response.